# Round list avatar

Tags: python, list, kivy

I'm trying simple list app with avatar. While I added my own picture it had been rectangle. I checked enternet but I didn't solved my problem.

Rectangle avatars

[image]

This is code:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineListItem, ImageLeftWidget, OneLineAvatarIconListItem

KV = '''
MDBoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"
    MDTopAppBar:
        title: "Telegram"
    MDScrollView:
        MDList:
            id: container
'''


class Example(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Light"
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def on_start(self):
        for i in range(20):
            def pr(self):
                print(self.id)
            self.root.ids.container.add_widget(
                OneLineAvatarIconListItem(ImageLeftWidget(
        source="sniper.jpg", on_release=pr), id=str(i), text=f"Single-line item {i}", on_release=pr))#.add_widget()

Example().run()
```

Comment: You can edit `sniper.jpg` and make it transparent in the areas not within the round area.

Comment: @JohnAnderson I appreciate your reply.  But I think there should be a way to do it in kivymd.  I left your answer as a last resort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use FitImage form kivymd to create your Rounded avatar and **make your own avatar list**. Here is how you can achieve this.

**Py File:-**

```
class Card(RoundedRectangularElevationBehavior, MDFloatLayout):
    pass

class DisplayPic(CircularElevationBehavior, ButtonBehavior, FitImage):
    pass
    
class ButtonLayout(RectangularRippleBehavior, ButtonBehavior, MDFloatLayout):
    pass
    
class UserCard(ButtonBehavior, Card):
        def __init__(self, name, dp, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(**kwargs)
            self.name = name
            self.dp = dp
```

KV File:-

```
<UserCard>
    size_hint: .9, None
    height: dp(80)
    elevation: dp(6)
    md_bg_color: 1,1,1,1
    soft_shadow_cl: [0, 0, 0, .05]
    radius: dp(20)
    name: ""
    dp: ""

                
    MDLabel:
        text: root.name
        bold:  True
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .75, 'center_y': .65}
    
    ButtonLayout:
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
        radius: root.radius

    DisplayPic:
        source: root.dp
        elevation: dp(3)
        size_hint: None, None
        size: dp(45), dp(45)
        radius: dp(360)
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .12, 'center_y': .5}
        on_release: print("clicked")
```

**Now You have your own avatar list element** just Use for loop to add your UserCard (avatar list element) to add it into a scroll view.

**How to use this element**:-

```
usercard = UserCard(u.display_name, u.photo_url)
```

Now add it to the ScrollView

**Full Code With your example:-**

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.behaviors import RoundedRectangularElevationBehavior, CircularElevationBehavior, RectangularRippleBehavior, CircularRippleBehavior
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior
from kivymd.uix.floatlayout import MDFloatLayout
from kivymd.uix.fitimage.fitimage import FitImage
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineListItem, ImageLeftWidget, OneLineAvatarIconListItem

KV = '''

<UserCard>
    size_hint: .9, None
    height: dp(80)
    elevation: dp(6)
    md_bg_color: 1,1,1,1
    soft_shadow_cl: [0, 0, 0, .05]
    radius: dp(20)
    name: ""
    dp: ""

                
    MDLabel:
        text: root.name
        bold:  True
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .75, 'center_y': .65}
    
    ButtonLayout:
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
        radius: root.radius

    DisplayPic:
        source: root.dp
        elevation: dp(3)
        size_hint: None, None
        size: dp(45), dp(45)
        radius: dp(360)
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .12, 'center_y': .5}
        on_release: print("clicked")


MDBoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"
    MDTopAppBar:
        title: "Telegram"
    ScrollView:
        MDGridLayout:
            id: container
            cols: 1
            col_force_default: False
            spacing: dp(6)
            size_hint: 1, .8
            adaptive_height: True
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5}
        
'''

class Card(RoundedRectangularElevationBehavior, MDFloatLayout):
    pass

class DisplayPic(CircularElevationBehavior, ButtonBehavior, FitImage):
    pass

class ButtonLayout(RectangularRippleBehavior, ButtonBehavior, MDFloatLayout):
    pass

class UserCard(ButtonBehavior, Card):
    def __init__(self, name, dp, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.name = name
        self.dp = dp

class Example(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Light"
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def change_screen(self, screen, receiver_name, receiver_uid, *args):
        receiver.name = receiver_name
        receiver.uid = receiver_uid
        self.manager.current = screen


    def on_start(self):
        for i in range(20):
            scrn_change = partial(self.change_screen, "Chat", u.display_name, u.uid)
            usercard = UserCard(u.display_name, u.photo_url)
            btn_layout = usercard.children[1]
            btn_layout.bind(on_release = scrn_change)
            self.root.ids.container.add_widget(usercard)
            

Example().run()
```

Output:-

[image]

Comment: can you convert it to my example? I don't understand

Comment: added full code with your example...